# Storage almost full for 14.10

Tags: 14.10, storage

I recently wiped my computer to have 14.10 as my only OS. It has 160 GB of storage. That was a month ago. Now, I keep getting prompts that the storage is almost full. And when I look it says I only have 543 MB free. How is this possible? I haven't torrented any large files. I do have Variety to autodownload wallpapers and not erase though.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1  146G  138G  554M  100%  / 
none 4.0K 0 4.0K 0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
udev 742M 4.0K 742M 1% /dev 
tmpfs 151M 1.1M 150M 1% /run 
none 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1% /run/lock 
none 752M 540K 751M 1% /run/shm 
none 100M 80K 100M 1% /run/user –  er –
```

Comment: There is any number of ways to fill empty space, which makes the question "How is it possible?" rather rhetorical. Can you post the output of `df -h` to give us some substance.

Comment: Maybe try run `baobab` in terminal to see what taking your storage

Comment: You could try running the Disk Usage Analyser, or Filelight to see what's taking up all that storage space.

Comment: This is the output for df -h @mikewhatever Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       146G  138G  554M 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            742M  4.0K  742M   1% /dev
tmpfs           151M  1.1M  150M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            752M  540K  751M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   80K  100M   1% /run/user

Comment: silly question, but is your trash empty?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Haha, yeah it's empty.

Comment: Now, you can check where all the free space is with this: `du -s /* 2>/dev/null | sort -nr`.

Comment: Doesn't `2>/dev/null` redirect stderr, but stderr is not piped to sort anyway, so isn't that unnecessary? Unless you don't want to see all those "permission denied" messages... Then it's like the root-only text summary from baobab

Answer (score 1):

With the output of `df -h`, really the problem is the huge usage on the disk sda1.

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
 /dev/sda1 146G 138G 554M 100% / 
 none      4.0K    0 4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
 udev      742M 4.0K 742M   1% /dev 
 tmpfs     151M 1.1M 150M   1% /run
 none      5.0M 4.0K 5.0M   1% /run/lock
 none      752M 540K 751M   1% /run/shm 
 none      100M  80K 100M   1% /run/user
```

use [disk usage analyser](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab) to drill down to the locations that have the biggest files and delete them.

If you are worried about the pop-up coming up while updating the kernel, head over to [removing old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels) - It saved me from the pop-ups.

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea what the space is being used by? I don't have any music saved locally.

Comment: @thatoneguy - You can find what it is used by using disk space analyzer. The problem for me to predict what your hard disk is being used for is - I cann't access it.

Comment: +1 for Disk usage analyzer (baobab), shows you exactly what's what

Answer (score 0):

Start with installing Ubuntu tweak, and clean all no longer needed files.

Go to the terminal and type or copy:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

run the program `ubuntu-tweak`

Comment: I thought I read that ubuntu-tweak was not recommended anymore, too many unstable systems resulting from it's use

Comment: I used it since ubuntu 10.04 and i had never problems. It is very safe.  You can use also bleach bit (it is in the repository) - but first use ubuntu tweak and afterwards bleach bit as user.  If the problem persist use bleach bit as root.

Comment: That's good news... there's always someone saying "don't do this, it's bad" about non-standard repo's, ppa's, tweak-type programs... non-debian repos, non-stable debian repos... pre-compiled bins, actually everything that's not made yourself in slackware I guess? haha